# bootstrap-datepicker частично отрабатывает в mozilla

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Использую `bootstrap-datepicker` выставляю свойства

```
startDate: new Date('01.01.2010'),
endDate: new Date()
```

В `chrome` все хорошо, нельзя выбрать даты раньше 2010 года и позже текущей даты, а вот в `mozilla` почему-то дизейблит любую дату, и нет возможности ее выбора, может кто знает как решить проблему?

Вот так в хроме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так вот в мазиле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в том что передавал дату не в том формате, нужно делать так:

```
startDate: new Date('2010-01-01'),
endDate: new Date()
```